# Numpy: Looking for efficient way to multiply a vector with a vandermonde matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Given two arrays `A` and `B` with the same size: `N`,
I'm trying to calculate the following product:

```
np.dot(A, np.vander(B, increasing=True))
```

However, If `N` becomes very large, I will eventually encounter an insufficient memory error.

This makes sense since the memory complexity is `N^2`.

Is there an efficient way to do this with memory complexity of `N` (i.e. avoiding initializing the vandermonde matrix), **without** using any loops?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation of the vandermonde matrix](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vander.html) you can construct it in the following way:

```
np.vander(B, increasing=True) == np.column_stack([B**(i) for i in range(len(B))])
```

So your optimization would be to do dot product in-place:

```
np.column_stack([np.dot(A, B**(i)) for i in range(len(B))])
```